# Mock System Environment Variable In C#

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to unit test the function which creates/Updates system environment variables.
So how do i test the above functions using Nunit in C#?

Answer (score 31):

Wrap the real calls that create/update the environment variables in class that can be dependency injected into your code. The two calls you need are:

```
string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variableName")

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("variableName", "value");
```

This latter always takes a string as the value.

Then the wrapper class will look something like this:

```
class MyEnvironment
{
    public string GetVariable(string variableName)
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variableName);
    }

    public void SetVariable(string variableName, string value)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(variableName, value);
    }
}
```

Then in your test suite inject the mock class that simulates the creation/updating. This will test the logic of your code.

The mocked class will look something like this:

```
class MockEnvironment
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _mockEnvironment;

    public string GetVariable(string variableName)
    {
        return _mockEnvironment[variableName];
    }

    public void SetVariable(string variableName, string value)
    {
        // Check for entry not existing and add to dictionary
        _mockEnviroment[variableName] = value;
    }
}
```

You need to test the wrapper class to make sure that it does actually create/update system environment variables, but you only need to do that the once.

Answer (score 11):

I can't answer as far as *mocking* environment variables, you would have to write your own `Environment` class for that.

In the general scope of accessing/setting environment variables, you can use [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example,

```
Assert.IsEqual("test", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test-var");
```

and for setup,

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("test-var", "test");
```

Answer (score 5):

I use a setup teardown model.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private string variable;
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        variable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VARIABLE");
    }
    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void OneTimeTearDown()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VARIABLE", variable);
    }
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VARIABLE", null);
    }
}
```